# how the natural policy gradient simplifies?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

in David Silver RL [course](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.silver/web/Teaching_files/pg.pdf) page 37 for "natural policy gradient"  Using compatible function approximation we have: 
[image]
So the natural policy gradient simplifies:
[image]
my question is how the above equation further simplified to the:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

compatible function approximation of advantage function has the following form:

$A^{\pi_\theta} (s, a) = \nabla_\theta\log \pi_{\theta}(s,a)^T w$

this form makes sure that we can use it instead of true advantage function and still get a proper direction of the gradient. You simply plug this expression in the equation and get the result.